# Iterating through string->string dict gives only the first character for each

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I have a `dict` as follows:

```
values  = {'A1' : '123456', 'B1' : 123456, ....}
```

I know that the correct way to iterate through is:

```
for key, value in values.items():
   #do what you want
```

By mistake, I forgot to add `.items()` and so I started getting strange `KeyError`

I tried printing and it was only getting the first character of each string and assigning it to `key` and `value`

My question is: why is python doing that? what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: Because it tries to do sequence unpacking.

Comment: It was trying to unpack `'A1'` and other keys as a tuple. By default iterating on a dictionary is like iterating on its keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write:

```
for x1,x2 in iterable:
    # ...
```

that actually means you do *sequence unpacking* in Python. Python evaluates it like:

```
x1,x2 = key0
```

Where `key0` is the first key (and of course other keys). This works if `key0` is an iterable that has *exactly* two elements. In that case the first element is assigned to `x1` and the second to `x2`.

Now a string is an iterable where its elements are the characters. So a string `'A1'` has two elements: `'A'` and `'1'`. This means that if you write:

```
key,value = 'A1'
```

`key` will hold `'A'` and `value` will hold `'1'`. Now if you print `key`, it will thus print the *first* value of the key.

Using a **`for` on a `values.items()` is no "magical expression"**: `items()` simply is an iterable that produces 2-tuples containing a key and the corresponding value. Since a tuple is also an iterable where the items are the elements of the tuple, the tuple is unpacked in the key and the value. So when you write: `for key,value in values.items()`, the `.items()` will generate a sequence like `('A1','123456')`, `('B1',123456)`. Now if such tuple is assigned to `key,value`, it is like writing:

```
key,value = ('A1','123456')
```

so `key` will take the first element of the tuple (`'A1'`) and `value` the second (`123456`).

Comment: ah! I thought it would unpack a tuple (`dict_key`, `dict_value`), I see now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: so are you saying  if my key strings had more than three characters the code won't work ? [Yes, I would get `too many values to unpack` error]

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi: indeed. You can however write `for key,*value in values`. In that case, `values` will be a list that captures the *remaining* elements.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way:

```
values  = {'A1' : '123', 'B1' : 456}

for key, value in values.items():
    #do what you want, e.g.
    print(key)
    print(value)

# result:
# A1
# 123
# B1
# 456
```

Now, without `.items()`:

```
values  = {'A1' : '123', 'B1' : 456}

for entry in values:
    print(entry)
    a,b = entry
    #do what you want, e.g.
    print(a)
    print(b)

# result:
# A1
# A
# 1
# B1
# B
# 1
```

As you can see, the script is reading each dictionary key and getting the first 2 elements from it (with strings behaving like lists).

Comment: The second code fragment does not work. Because when you do a `for` on `entry`. You well get the chars of the string. And those cannot be unpacked further.